# character RPG stat generation

Tags: python, list, discord.py

So I've been working on a python rpg game, recently, and I've ran into a problem that can't be easily solved with my current python skills, to give some background, the problem I'm facing is with the level function of my game, which is used to generate enemies, each enemies within my game, has attributes like: health, strength, **magic, speed, defense and logic(defense against magic)**, and they also have a class, for example let's say that we are generating a level 75 ninja enemy.

ninja class's growth rate: Max Health 60%, Strength 40%, Magic 15%, Speed 60%, Defense 30%, Logic 20%

in order to generate the stats of the enemy:
I would loop 75 times because that's the level of the ninja, and every time I loop, I would run through the growth rates and run the growth rate chances, if it's returns true, then I add 1 to that stat, example:

```
array indexs [MaxHP, Strength, Magic, Speed, Defense, Logic]\
Level 1 iteration: [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
Level 2 iteration: [2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
Level 3 iteration: [2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1]
Level 4 iteration: [3, 2, 0, 3, 1, 1]
the algorithm would do this 75 times
```

as you can see that the stats slowly begin to reflect the growth rate, as the ninja would end up with better stats in max health, strength and speed.

**Now the problem is that this algorithm is being run constantly within a multiplayer game, on my puny raspberry pi, all I am asking is that would there be a more efficient way to generate enemies, cause right now to generate a level 75 ninja, I need to run the rng 75*6 = 450 times, which isn't great efficiency wise**

Here's the code for the algorithm

```py
def generate_enemy(name,level):
    #used the 0 at the start as placement for the message id
    weapon_type = random.choice(list(class_road_map.keys()))
    num_classes = min(int(level/20)+1,len(class_road_map[weapon_type]))
    classes = class_road_map[weapon_type][:num_classes]
    for num in range(len(classes)):
        classes[num] = random.choice(classes[num].split("-"))
    weapon_thing = generate_class_weapon(classes[-1],level)
    weapon_id = game.hash_string(weapon_thing)
    current_level = 0
    enemy_data = [0, name, weapon_id, classes[-1], level, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,generate_enemy_loot(level),""]
    for class_name in classes:
        growth_rates = db.get_class(class_name)[1].split("-")
        for x in range(20):
            if current_level == level:
                break
            current_level+=1
            for num in range(len(growth_rates)):
                if rng(float(growth_rates[num])):
                    enemy_data[7+num]+=1
    enemy_data[6] = enemy_data[7]
    return enemy_data
```

If you are interested in the project, please check out the GitHub repo
https://github.com/Graves451/discord-based-rpg

Comment: I dont see why you cant just go with something like randInt(moblevel-10, moblevel) and just go with that? What is purpose of growth if the end result is still going to end up near its level?

Comment: the problem is that randint generates a random number, while I need the number to stay somewhat close to the growth rate times the level, so like the strength stat of the level 75 ninja should be around 40% times 75, so around 30, not deviating too much.

Comment: What about `0.4*75 + randint(-5, 5)`? This way you will have an even spread between 25 and 35. You can change the `randint(-5, 5)` to be whatever you like. Needs one `randint` call per attribute.

Comment: that could work, however, I would probably have to rework it so that smaller levels would have a smaller range of possible values

Comment: however, all those stats that range from (-5,5) still has the same probability, which I don't like, I think something more like a weighted random number generator would do a better job, because the spread should be closer to the middle rather than all the possible values having the same probability